# how to map multiple keys to aliases in yargs .alias

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, yargs

[Yargs api](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#aliaskey-alias) says about .alias(key, alias):

> Optionally .alias() can take an object that maps keys to aliases. Each key of this object should be the canonical version of the option, and each value should be a string or an array of strings.

I tried to find example but i didn't found. can someone give code example of that option?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
      .alias({
         help: 'h',
         version: 'v'
       })
```

instead of:

```
      .alias('help', 'h)
      .alias('version, 'v)
```